# Agent job Failed | ##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant,

Tags: azure-devops

When i running the pipeline job in azredevops it's getting the below error., Please check and provide us the grant permissions.

ERROR: ##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please reach out to azpipelines-freetier@microsoft.com with your name and organization name

When i sent a mail to above mentioned email address but there is no use.

Please help us the how to resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

To unblock and continue, you'll, unfortunately, need to send the email as requested.

Reference:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-private-projects/
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/